# How do you pass variables to pageQuery

Tags: gatsby

I have this page in Gatsby:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'

import IntroPartial from '../partials/themes/intro'

export default class ThemeTemplate extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const theme = this.props.pathContext.theme
    console.dir(this.data)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{theme.name}</h1>
        <IntroPartial theme={theme} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query ThemeQuery($theme: String){
  allMarkdownRemark(
    filter: { frontmatter: { themes: { in: [$theme] } } }
  ){
    edges{
      node{
        frontmatter{
          title
          themes
        }
        html
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

This query works fine in the GraphQL tester assuming I supply an option to `$theme`. How do I provide the value for `$theme`? I'd like to set it to `this.props.pathContext.theme.slug`.

The docs seem to imply that some variables should just work, but I'm not sure how to add my own.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The variables passed into graphql are coming from [createPage](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/bound-action-creators/#createPage). It's normally called in your gatsby-node file. You'll often see path used, as $path, in examples as it is required.

In order to include your own, additional variables to pass into the graphql call, you'll need to add them to context. Modifying the example from the docs a bit:

```
createPage({
  path: `/my-sweet-new-page/`,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/my-sweet-new-page.js`),
  // The context is passed as props to the component as well
  // as into the component's GraphQL query.
  context: {
   theme: `name of your theme`,
 },
})
```

You can then use $theme in the query as you have in your example. Setting $theme in the above code would be done in the [createPages](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages) portion (see the example), as you'll then have access to all of the data.

Comment: I have to say that `graphql` in the component is the biggest blackbox in `gatsby`. If it wasn't for you then I would have never known that the `graphql variable` was coming from `createPage` albeit it's in the docs.

Comment: Is there any reason why this won't be working? I'm using same code, but filter not working on pages, but works in gql browser