# How to use output of one query in another GraphQL Gatsby

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby - In one of my layouts I have a query that gets posts for a given month.

I want to make that query dynamic to get the month from the site metadata and pass to that query.

```
site {
    siteMetadata {
      month
    }
  }
```

results in `site.siteMetadata.month = "November 2018"`

Then pass that Month to the next query

```
  query ($month: String!){
  allWordpressPost(filter: {tags: {name: {eq: $month}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        excerpt
        slug
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        categories {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass variables to pageQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365205/how-do-you-pass-variables-to-pagequery)

Comment: Query variables are defined through `context` provided to the `createPage` call. In your `gatsby-node.js` you can use the `graphql` function to run a query for your `siteMetadata`, then call `createPage` with the relevant context (e.g. `month`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365205/how-do-you-pass-variables-to-pagequery for more info.