# GraphQL retrieve data for specific blocks - Gatsby + Wordpress

Tags: graphql, advanced-custom-fields, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api

I have a React + Gatsby JS project that retrieves data from a Wordpress site through their headless API. I'm a total newbie to Gatsby.

Every page on my site is made up of blocks, which are in turn made up of fields. I'm using ACF to build these.

I am currently able to retrieve every page and a list of the blocks within that page by using the following GraphQL query:

```
 query ($id: String!) {
        currentPage: wordpressPage(id: {eq: $id}) {
            title
            acf {
                page_blocks {
                 block_type {
                     acf_fc_layout
                 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This returns the following data for page with id `f4c4f4a7-ba0d-55b1-8877-16f543c22b80`

```
{
  "data": {
    "wordpressPage": {
      "id": "f4c4f4a7-ba0d-55b1-8877-16f543c22b80",
      "acf": {
        "page_blocks": [
          {
            "block_type": [
              {
                "acf_fc_layout": "page_title_and_text"
              },
              {
                "acf_fc_layout": "two_column_media_and_text"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The blocks are next to `afc_fc_layout`. Both `page_title_and_text` and `two_column_media_and_text` are page blocks in that page.

Now, I would think that the next step would be to make a React component for each of those blocks, passing in the custom field data for each, to that component. If a page doesn't have a block, then there wouldn't be a need for me to retrieve the fields for that block, right?

Initially I thought I would run another query from my React component, requesting the fields for that particular block. But I realized I can't really add variables (page Id) to a static query within my components, per [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/), so I wouldn't be able to query that specific page for its fields. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I believe I have to retrieve those fields I need from my main query that I've shown you here, but it seems absolutely bonkers to have to query for every possible custom field on the site, when not all pages are going to have the same blocks.

Ideally there would be some sort of syntax like

```
...
acf {
    page_blocks {
        block_type {
            acf_fc_layout
            if (acf_fc_layout eq page_title_and_text) {
                title 
                text
            }

            if (acf_fc_layout eq two_column_media_and_text) {
                media
                text
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

And then I would pass those fields to their corresponding React component.

What is the proper way to go about this?

Note: I am currently at the point where I'm able to retrieve the fields from the API to render blocks. I am more wondering if there is any way my graphQL query can filter out the data for me, or if there is a way to customize the WP endpoint to show me field data filtered by the blocks that are actually on the page.

Ex: the site queries the data in blocks 4,3,2,10,12,15.... even though the page only has block 2.

I'm worried that devs that want to add blocks in the future will have to rewrite the query each time, hurting the site's scalability and potential performance.

Answer (score 3):

You say you are a beginner with Gatsby but what you are trying to do touches many advanced topics inside Gatsby. My answer is most likely incomplete and you will need to figure many things out for yourself.

Prepare yourself for lots of documentation reading and lots of debugging to get things to work with Gatsby.

---

You want to [programmatically create pages](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/) depending on the result of your GraphQL query. That means you need to create a page wide page template component.

In your `templates` folder of your Gatsby project, you create one template that programmatically picks the right components for each of your routes. To get your ACF data you use GraphQL [page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/).

> What is the proper way to go about this?

One alternative is this: You create React components that retrieve their data via props. You don't need to give each of those components their own GraphQL query since you already query in your page templates.

acf: acf_fc_layout eq page_title_and_text -> React component `PageTitleAndText.jsx`

```
const PageTitleAndText = ({ title, text}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// NO GraphQL query

export default PageTitleAndText;
```

Instead, you pass props inside your page template to your component:

`acfPageTemplate.jsx`

```
const acfPageTemplate = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {/* pass props as data from the GraphQL query result here */}
        <PageTitleAndText title={props.data.currentPage.acf.page_blocks.block_type.acf_fc_layout.title  } 
                          text ={props.data.currentPage.acf.page_blocks.block_type.acf_fc_layout.text} />

    </div>
  );
};
export const query = graphql`
 query ($id: String!) {
        currentPage: wordpressPage(id: {eq: $id}) {
            title
            acf {
                page_blocks {
                 block_type {
                     acf_fc_layout
                 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

export default acfPageTemplate;
```

Define a page template for each of your acf layouts. Pick the right components for each layout and pass props as data from the GraphQL query result.

You need to pass variables to your page query. The only way to do this is to use page context as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365205/how-do-you-pass-variables-to-pagequery):

`gatsby-node.js`

```
createPage({
  path: `/my-acf-page-title-and-text-page/`,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/PageTitleAndText.jsx`),
  // The context is passed as props to the component as well
  // as into the component's GraphQL query.
  context: {
   id: acfFieldId, // pass the acf field id
 },
})

// define a createPage action for each of your acf layouts
```

---

> But I realized I can't really add variables (page Id) to a static query within my components, per Gatsby docs, so I wouldn't be able to query that specific page for its fields. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Correct. That's why you need to go the way with a page query, page template, and page context variable in `gatsby-node.js`

> If a page doesn't have a block, then there wouldn't be a need for me to retrieve the fields for that block, right?

Yes. That's why you create a different page template for each of your acf layouts. You can create one big tempalte for all layouts but then you need to programmatically decide what components to add. This is out of scope of this question. You should ask a new question if you want to do this.

My advise is to get this to work with one specific layout before you go down this next rabbit hole, if you decide to do this at all.

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer. I actually did follow all the instructions. I'm creating pages with Gatsby-node.js, using the page template to query the API and retrieve all my fields and I am now stuck at the step in which the blocks are rendered within that page template. The site that I'm trying to implement doesn't have consistency across pages. All pages have different blocks in different orders, so I can't really make a page template for each layout. So my question was more, how do I retrieve my block information efficiently without having to query blocks that are not in the page.

Comment: So for example, if my site has 45 blocks in total with a set of custom fields in each, do I really need to query every field in those 45 blocks every time the page template is loaded, or can I query based on what blocks are actually within that page. So if a page has blocks 1, 5 and 6, could the query skip the other ones? Or do I have to have a potentially few hundred line long query?

Comment: Gatsby "loads" the template once at build time. Once the site is built, it does not matter how complicated or efficient the query is. Learn about the build process here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/

Comment: First get the template to work with only one block with the way I described. This way you can get closer to a solution step by step. From there you should ask a new question where you describe in detail how blocks refer to fields, and how you need help about skipping blocks and such.

Comment: Having a query that queries every possible custom field, potentially hundreds of them, for every page seems convoluted and it doesn't make the site easily scalable. Also I am currently able to display the fields for one block as you said. I'm not sure that a new question would be different from this one. 

Somebody also suggested I look into building a custom endpoint on my Wordpress side that gives me information for blocks based on that page solely. I have no idea how to go about that or if it's possible.