# Gatsby - how to pass variables to pageQuery

Tags: gatsby

I have same problem as in [How do you pass variables to pageQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365205/how-do-you-pass-variables-to-pagequery), but for some reason solution not working for me

`console.log` inside template shows that data passed properly to component and `pageContext` is `{cat: "Cat Name", limit: 10}`, but query result returns items with category different from applied filter. Same query works fine and returns filtered list inside GraphiQL explorer.

my template component:

```
const Page: FC<unknown> = ({pageContext}): React.ReactElement => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)
  console.log(data, query, pageContext)

...

const query = graphql`
  query GetItems($cat: String, $limit: Int) {
    items: allItems(limit: $limit, filter: { category: { eq: $cat } }) {
```

my creatPage part:

```
console.log(cat)
createPage({
      path: `cat/${cat.slug}`,
      component: template,
      context: {
        cat: cat.title,
        limit: 10
      },
    })
```

So the question is - what am I doing wrong, and what can I do to debug it?

**EDIT:** so I did not read docs carefully enough, and `useStaticQuery` I copy-pasted from other pages can't accept variables. I tried to remove it, but did not get `data` prop in my component. I will update question bit later with additional information on what I changed.

Comment: ok, seems I was stupid and did not read docs careful enough. StaticQuery can't accept variables

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
{cat: "Cat Name", limit: 10}
```

I don't know if it's a typo, but `title` is not a property of `cat`. If so, fix it, otherwise, `cat: cat.title`, will become `undefined`.

In addition, you can create a sample query to be used in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` by adding manually the context values:

```
  query GetItems {
    items: allItems(limit: 10, filter: { category: { eq: "Cat Name"} }) {

     ...
    }
```

Then, you will be able to test your expected results accordingly.

Comment: sample query at `localhost:8000/___graphql` is what I mentioned by `Same query works fine and returns filtered list inside GraphiQL explorer.` - it works fine, when tested like that

Comment: and `{cat: "Cat Name", limit: 10}` is result of `console.log(data, query, pageContext)` which I edited, sorry if it was unclear. it's `pageContext` part, which I assume, should be passed to graphql query by gatsby

Comment: updated question a bit to make it clearer

Comment: ok, seems I was stupid and did not read docs careful enough. StaticQuery can't accept variables

Comment: Exactly, hence the name. You can use a page query on a page component and pass down the data to your component